# force close and i dont know why

Tags: java, android

Currently i'm developing android application but it keep force closing. I will post the codes i have done. The testproject gui was just one simple button. By right when i click the button, it should go to the camera class. However, it force closes. I run the camera itself and it works. :/

**Testproject class :**

```
  package com.example.testproject;

  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.content.Intent;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
  import android.widget.Button;

  public class Testproject extends Activity {

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.menu);

Button bc;

bc = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btncamera); 

bc.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v){
        Intent intent = new Intent(Testproject.this, Camera.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});

}

    }
```

Camera class :

```
    package com.example.testproject;

    import java.io.IOException;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.ImageButton;
    import android.widget.ImageView;

    public class Camera extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener     {

ImageButton ib;
Button b;
ImageView iv;
Intent i;
final static int cameraResults = 0;
Bitmap bmp;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.camera);
    initialize();
}

public void initialize(){
    iv = (ImageView) findViewById (R.id.ivReturnedPic);
    ib = (ImageButton) findViewById (R.id.ibTakePic);
    b = (Button) findViewById (R.id.bSetWall);
    b.setOnClickListener(this);
    ib.setOnClickListener(this);

}

    @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch (v.getId()){
    case R.id.bSetWall:
        try {
            getApplicationContext().setWallpaper(bmp);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
         break;

    case R.id.ibTakePic:
        i = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(i,cameraResults);
        break;
    }

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        bmp = (Bitmap)extras.get("data");
        iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);

    }
}

    }
```

Comment: Post your LogCat output.  If the app is force closing, surely there's an error message in LogCat.

Comment: oh. speaking about logcat. i totally forgotten about the logcat. haha. managed to solve the error. thanks!

Comment: @user2316009: If you fixed the problem, consider adding your own answer. It will help others visiting this page in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have all the proper permissions in your `manifest.xml` file.  If you are using the camera, you'll need:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure u have added your `camera` activity in the `manifest.xml`.

Comment: For anyone who meet problem like this, it often happens because you might have forgotten to add the activity in the manifest. 
Here is the manifest activity code, it vary for different people but it's pretty standardized.

Here is the manifest code : 
            <activity
            android:name=".Camera"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />